# Shell script save terminal (screen) outputs

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-screen

I have a USB-Dongle that can recive radio signals (868Mhz).
This dongle coud be controlled over a screen terminal session:

```
screen /dev/ttyACM0
```

In this Terminal all 120sec  appear strings:

```
T350B00B64C19
```

How can I save this strings in a variable to work with them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting `screen` with the `-L` option creates a log in the current working directory. I guess that should serve your requirements.

```
$ screen --help
...
-L            Turn on output logging.
...
```

From `man 1 screen`:

```
-L   tells screen to turn on automatic output logging for the windows.
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you don't actually need `screen`; you just need to read from the serial device. For example:

```
while read data; do
    # Work with value in $data
done < /dev/ttyACM0
```

Each call to `read` should block until the dongle writes another string to the serial device.

If you need to send commands to the device, you can also simply write the appropriate string to the same file:

```
printf "my-command" > /dev/ttyACM0
read response < /dev/ttyACM0
```